# Hangfire run job only after finishing the previous ones

Tags: c#, jobs, job-scheduling, hangfire

I want the GetCachedRequisicoes job to be run only when all GetRequisicao jobs have completed successfully.

```
 public Task<object> ProcessarRequisicoes(PerformContext context, string empresa, int fornecedor, List<ReqFornecSistemaDto> paylaod, long parentId)
    {
        try
        {
            //var result = context.GetAntecedentResult<List<ReqFornecSistemaDto>>();
            var jobId = context.BackgroundJob.Id;
            context.SetJobParameter("PROCESSED", jobId);
            var requisicaoJobs = new List<string>();
            BatchJob.Attach(context.GetBatchId(), batch =>
            {
                foreach (var item in paylaod)
                    batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetRequisicao(null, empresa, item.Sistema, item.Local, item.Produto));

                jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetCachedRequisicoes(null));
                jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.GetIdFornecedorProcurement(null, empresa, fornecedor));
                jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IMapperService>(jobId, x => x.MapFromAntecedentResult(null, typeof(Lar.Procurement.Client.RequisicaoCompra.RequestWrapper), null));
                jobId = batch.ContinueJobWith<IRequisicaoCompraService>(jobId, x => x.Send(null));
                batch.ContinueJobWith<IHookTargetService>(jobId, x => x.AtualizarFinalizado(null, parentId, TargetHook.PROCUREMENT));
            });

            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception.Failin();
        }
    }
```

How can I do this?